# jquery change() works only once in a form

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a small script problem with jQuery. I tried to make a form with 2 radio buttons and a select list. I want that if the user clicks on the list it would check the "email" and the radio should get checked if the user click on the radio "livredor", I need to make it "autochecked".

This code only works once. If the radio buttons get clicked it's stuck.

```js
$("#destinataires").change(function() {
  $('input[type=radio][name=choix][value=email]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<INPUT id="emailchoix" name="choix" type="radio" value="email">

<SELECT id="destinataires" name="contact" size="1">
    <option value="etienne">Étienne</option>
    <option value="michele">Michèle</option>
    <option value="thomas">Thomas</option>
    <option value="filou">Filou</option>
    <option value="mustapha">Mustapha</option>
</SELECT>

<INPUT id="livrechoix" type="radio" name="choix" value="livredor"> Livredor
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery's `prop()` to set the checked state, instead of `attr()`.
According to the documentation for [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method
>   should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr()
>   method.

```js
$("#destinataires").change(function() {
  $('input[type=radio][name=choix][value=email]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="emailchoix" name="choix" type="radio" value="email">

<select id="destinataires" name="contact" size="1">
    <option value="etienne">Étienne</option>
    <option value="michele">Michèle</option>
    <option value="thomas">Thomas</option>
    <option value="filou">Filou</option>
    <option value="mustapha">Mustapha</option>
</select>

<input id="livrechoix" type="radio" name="choix" value="livredor" checked> Livredor
```

For a more technical explanation, see [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).